# Vuetifyjs 2.0 theme doesn't change with watchers

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

With Vuetifyjs v1.5 i was able to change the theme dynamically using vue watchers.
This is not working anymore with Vuetifyjs 2.0

Vue version: 2.6.10
Vuetify: 2.0
Vuex: 3.1.1

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      darkEnabled: this.$store.state.darkEnabled
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.$vuetify.theme.dark = this.darkEnabled;
  },
  watch: {
    'this.$store.state.darkEnabled'(oldValue, newValue) {
      this.$vuetify.theme.dark = newValue;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is triggering your mutation?

Comment: A method in another component:
setCurrentTheme() {
   this.$store.commit('setDarkEnable', !this.$store.state.darkEnabled);
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First value of watcher callback is newValue. You have flapped order and assigning old value always . Is should be `(newValue, oldValue)`
Also, it should be `'$store.state.darkEnabled'(newValue)` without `this`.

Comment: Done, but still not working. If you console log new value before assigning it, nothing is printed so it’s like watcher not working

Comment: try `'$store.state.darkEnabled'(newValue)`

Comment: That happens. We miss the most obvious :)